# La función de la raiz cuadrada, sqrt(), me retorna 0

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con este código y es que la función `sqrt()` me devuelve 0. Todo lo demás anda bien pero no se porque no me anda la raíz.

No se si sera la librería o si lo estoy escribiendo mal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main(){

    double x1, y1, x2, y2;

    puts("***distancia de dos puntos***");

    printf("x1 es:"); scanf("%d",&x1);

    printf("y1 es:"); scanf("%d",&y1);

    printf("el punto 1 es (%d,%d)",x1, y1);

    printf("\nx2 es:"); scanf("%d",&x2);
    printf("y2 es:"); scanf("%d",&y2);
    printf("el punto 2 es (%d,%d)\n",x2, y2);

    x1=x2-x1;
    y1=y2-y1;

    printf("x1:%d y y2:%d\n",x1, y1);

    puts("la distancia entre los dos puntos es:");
    printf("distancia es:%d",sqrt((x1*x1)+(y1*y1)));

    return;
}
```

Comment: Eso claramente no es c#

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios errores en tu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    double x1, y1, x2, y2, radicando;

    puts("*** Distancia de dos Puntos ***");

    // Las variables double se leen con %lf no con %d
    printf("x1 es:"); scanf("%lf",&x1);
    printf("y1 es:"); scanf("%lf",&y1);

    // Lo mismo sucede a la hora de usar printf, debes usarlo con %lf
    // en %.2lf, el .2 indica el número de decimales a mostrar
    printf("El punto 1 es (%.2lf, %.2lf)", x1, y1);


    printf("\nx2 es:"); scanf("%lf",&x2);
    printf("y2 es:"); scanf("%lf",&y2);
    
    printf("el punto 2 es (%.2lf, %.2lf)\n", x2, y2);

    // Aqui por claridad primero calculamos el radicando
    radicando = pow((x2 - x1), 2) + pow((y2 - y1), 2);

    // mostramos el resultado calculando la raiz cuadrada del radicando
    printf("la distancia entre los dos puntos es: %.2lf", sqrt(radicando));

    // el programa termina con return 0;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: fuaaa  parece que la tenes re clara muchas gracias ahora si funciono sos crack